# How do I turn on brush diameter display in texture paint mode?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm not sure if this is new to 2.7 or not, but I can't seem to figure out how to make my cursor display as the width of the paint brush when I'm in texture paint mode.  I can muddle through all right- I mean, *it technically works*- but since the cursor is alwyas a pointer arrow, figuring out exactly what's going to be painted and where is kind of a crapshoot until I press the mouse button.

I know from tutorials that isn't how it ought to be, but can't for the life of me figure out what preference or setting might be flipped.  (NB: I'm brand new to Blender with this release, so following tutorials and trying to discern the weird bits that are me-fucking-up versus what's simply different in the new release is rough...)

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: It should show a circle for the brush radius by default.. Does it appear if you press *Reload factory settings* in the *File* menu at the top of the window, then switch to texture paint mode?

Comment: No luck there: loaded factory settings, and still have a pointer cursor for the brush.   (It also erased the texture I was working on as a cute little bonus.  I didn't realize you have to save images separately from the .blend file. ugh.)

Comment: Oops, sorry about that :/ I should have mentioned that you should probably try it out on a new file first.

Answer (score 5):

In Texture Paint Mode, Go to Options Panel >> Appearance >> and Select the Show Brush check box.

[image: Disabled]
[image: Enabled]